# Echo `workon` works but echo `workon env_name` doesn't

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to automate running python environment on startup but struggling with a problem. Here is my code.

```
venv=`env | grep virtualenvwrapper.sh | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
source $venv
workon blog_dev
```

But nothing happens. **Blog_dev** exists, I can switch to it by manually typing `workon blog_dev`. I've tried some commands from **virtualenvwrapper**

```
mkvirtualenv blog_test
```

creates **blog_test** virtualenv and activates it

```
deactivate blog_test
```

deactivates **blog_test** virtualenv

```
workon
```

or

```
lsvirtualenv -b
```

returns a list of virtualenvs.
Only `workon blog_dev` has no effect.

What should I do?

Comment: Where do you run this code? As a startup script? In .bashrc? Note `workon env_name` has no ouptut.

Comment: For test I run it with `./script.sh` and virtualenv isn't activated.